# iPhone Internationalization. What is the simplest workflow for me?

Tags: iphone, internationalization, nib, nslocalizedstring

I am wising up and getting my internationalization act together. Right off the bat I am a bit swamped by all the docs Apple provides so I was wondering of someone could sketch a workflow for my situation.

Before I begin, I browsed some Apple example code and noticed this NIB file - MainWindow.xib - in the Resources folder:

[alt text http://daturner.com/stackoverflow/nib.jpg](http://daturner.com/stackoverflow/nib.jpg)

This clearly has something to do with internationalization/localization. Could someone please explain how this is created and where in the workflow it happens?

My app is fundamentally an imaging app with a few labels that I currently programmatically internationalize using NSLocalizedString(...). If I set all my labels programmatically and wrap all my strings with NSLocalizedString(...) can I completely ignore the NIB issues?

Thanks in advance,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your last part of the question: Yes!

In my experience, it can be a pain to localize Nib's so if at all possible try to limit the localization effort to .strings files.

Comment: Thanks Claus. I was hoping I would hear that. Cheers.